# Is it possible to promote a value to type level?

Tags: haskell, data-kinds

Doing this just for fun but I don't end up figuring this out.

Say I have a typeclass that unifies coordinate system on squares and hexagons:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.Proxy

data Shape = Square | Hexagon

class CoordSystem (k :: Shape) where
  type Coord k

  -- all coordinates arranged in a 2D list
  -- given a side length of the shape
  allCoords :: forall p. p k -> Int -> [[Coord k]]

  -- neighborhoods of a coordinate.
  neighborsOf :: forall p. p k -> Int -> Coord k -> [Coord k]

-- omitting implementations
instance CoordSystem 'Square
instance CoordSystem 'Hexagon
```

Now suppose I want to use this interface with a `s :: Shape` that is only known at runtime. But to make use of this interface, at some point I'll need a function like this:

```hs
-- none of those two works:
-- promote :: CoordSystem k => Shape -> Proxy (k :: Shape) -- signature 1
-- promote :: Shape -> forall k. CoordSystem k => Proxy (k :: Shape)

promote s = case s of
  Square -> Proxy @'Square
  Hexagon -> Proxy @'Hexagon
```

However this does not work, if signature 1 is uncommented:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘k’ with ‘'Square’
      ‘k’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          promote :: forall (k :: Shape). CoordSystem k => Shape -> Proxy k
        at SO.hs:28:1-55
      Expected type: Proxy k
        Actual type: Proxy 'Square
```

Understandably, none of `'Square`, `'Hexagon`, `k :: Shape` unifies with others, so I have no idea whether this is possible.

I also feel type erasure shouldn't be an issue here as alternatives of `Shape` can use to uniquely identify the instance - for such reason I feel [singletons](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons) could be of use but I'm not familiar with that package to produce any working example either.

Comment: in similar situations I tend to provide the function doing the `case` - analysis (deciding what type to deserilize etc.) with a "action"/"continuation" of sorts (using type-classes or just simply one per type) - like `myFun withSquare withHexagon = ... case s of ... Square -> withSquare squareData ...` - aside from that existentials should work too

Comment: of course good old plain adts should be an option too `data ShapeData = Square SquareData | Hexagon HexagonData` ;)

Answer (score 4):

The usual way is to use either an existential type or its Church encoding. The encoded version is actually easier to understand at first, I think, and closer to what you already attempted. The problem with your `forall k. CoordSystem k => {- ... thing mentioning k -}` is that it promises to polymorph into whatever `k` the user likes (so long as the user likes `CoordSystem`s!). To fix it, you can demand that the *user* polymorph into whatever `k` *you* like.

```
                              -- `a` must not mention `k`, since `k` is not
                              -- in scope in the final return type
promote :: forall a. Shape -> (forall k. CoordSystem k => Tagged k a) -> a
promote Square a = unTagged (a @Square)
promote Hexagon a = unTagged (a @Hexagon)

-- usage example
test = promote Hexagon (unproxy $ \p -> length (allCoords p 15))
```

Note that on the right hand side of the `=` sign, `a` has the type `forall k. CoordSystem k => {- ... -}` that says the user gets to choose `k`, but this time you're the user.

Another common option is to use an existential:

```
data SomeSystem where
    -- Proxy to be able to name the wrapped type when matching on a SomeSystem;
    -- in some future version of GHC we may be able to name it via pattern-matching
    -- on a type application instead, which would be better
    SomeSystem :: CoordSystem k => Proxy k -> SomeSystem
```

Then you would write something like

```
promote :: Shape -> SomeSystem
promote Square = SomeSystem (Proxy @Square)
promote Hexagon = SomeSystem (Proxy @Hexagon)

-- usage example
test = case promote Hexagon of SomeSystem p -> length (allCoords p 15)
```

and then the user would pattern match to extract the `CoordSystem` instance from it.

A final choice is singletons:

```
data ShapeS k where
    SquareS :: ShapeS Square
    HexagonS :: ShapeS Hexagon
```

Here we have made a direct connection between `SquareS` at the computation level and `Square` at the type level (resp. `HexagonS` and `Hexagon`). Then you can write:

```
                       -- N.B. not a rank-2 type, and in particular `a` is
                       -- now allowed to mention `k`
promote :: ShapeS k -> (CoordSystem k => a) -> a
promote SquareS a = a
promote HexagonS a = a
```

The `singletons` package offers tools for automatically deriving the singleton types that correspond to your ADTs.

Comment: I added usage examples for the first two.  (In particular, it wasn't obvious to me how to use the first one until I went through the process.)  As far as I can see, the singletons version of `promote` isn't useful as written; rather, singletons would be a general approach to avoid needing to define `promote` in the first place, I guess.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr I guess using it in a way analogous to your other examples would look like `test = length (promote HexagonS allCoords HexagonS 15)`.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr ...but then, I guess `length (allCoords HexagonS 15)` achieves the same thing without `promote`, which maybe is your point. *shrug*

Comment: @K.A.Buhr Then again, compare the types of `allCoords` and `\s -> promote s allCoords s` and you'll notice that the latter does not have a class constraint, which can be interesting in certain circumstances.